# Line chart doesn't populate the actual values

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a basic Excel sheet having date and time values:

[image: Main Excel Sheet]

SLA should be a straight line @ 8:30. The remaining two columns should display the lines for those specific dates. It would look something like this:

[image: Something like this]

For now, my image looks something like this:

[image: Currently Looks like this]

The spiked ones are the dates which crossed the SLA. Other points are below the entire spreadsheet.

The point is, it doesn't show a timeline for each date. My current chart "Select Data" section is like this image:

[image: Select Data Section]

I want lines drawn for each and every date.

Comment: It looks like you're missing a few images referenced in the post.

Comment: SuperUser allows me to add just 2 at a time.

Comment: Looking for something like this 
http://imgur.com/a/x8nOt
http://imgur.com/N5zyhwk

Comment: I added the images, does that look correct?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use dates for the X axis, you need to apply a trick when selecting the data for the chart. With a column label for the dates, Excel tries to interpret the column as a series, and that goes horribly wrong.

These are the steps I took to create the chart in the screenshot

1. Remove the data label above the date column.
2. Select the data, including the labels, so the top left corner of the selection is the blank cell above the dates, A1 in the screenshot
3. insert a stacked column chart
4. select the SLA series in the chart and change the series chart type to line.
5. format to your liking

[image]

By the way, it does not make much sense to stack completion time on top of indicated time. What you really want here is the difference if completion time is later than indicated time.

Comment: I modified it as per your instructions.. I am unable to view entire data datewise though prntscr.com/cyknc5

Comment: Start with a smaller data sample and add data to it until you figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Why are some of your time values left-aligned? Looks like text instead of numbers and would explain why they don't plot. The plot seems to be OK for October data. Check your data.